# How to make an array of Objects into an Array of String

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have an array such as:

```
let arr = [{subject: "BSE", courseCode: "1010"},{subject: "STA", courseCode: "2020"}];
```

Is it possible to make the array only containing the value pairs of the object such as:

```
let result = ["BSE","1010","STA","2020"];
```

Comment: Object.values(Obj) gives you the list of values for `Obj`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Object.prototype.values`, you can generate only values from an object.

```js
let arr = [{subject: "BSE", courseCode: "1010"},{subject: "STA", courseCode: "2020"}];

const output = arr.flatMap((item) => Object.values(item));
console.log(output);
```